# module is not defined error

Tags: node.js, meteor, atmosphere, meteorite

I am using nodejs in my meteor app and I added packages using `mrt add npm` and then in my client directory in `packages.json` I added `skimlinksjs` and its version and it is added to my app.

When I tried to using them in my app in server side code like this,

```
var res;
var skim = Meteor.require('skimlinksjs');
var apili = Meteor.require('/config.js');
skim.setup(apili.key);
skim.query({
    searchFor: "title:\"moto g\"",
    fq: "country:US"
  }, function(err,data) {
    res=data.skimlinksProductAPI.numFound;
  }
);
return res;
```

and my `config.js` file is like this

```
module.exports = {
    key: "xxxxxxx"
}
```

whenI'm running this application it is showing error like

```
module not defined
```

What went wrong with my code or is there any need to install other packages?

Comment: doesn't `/config.js` mean that the file lives in the root directory of your drive? you probably mean `./config.js`, no?

Comment: i tried that too. But it is not working.

Comment: oh, the other thing you probably missed is that meteor doesn't run node in the directory you might be thinking. Print `process.env['PWD']` and you'll see. There were questions about that here frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just  got the answer

Write this function in server side code

```
function returnAllResult()
{
    var skimlinks = Meteor.require('skimlinksjs');
    skimlinks.setup("xxx");
    var skimlinks_query = Async.wrap(skimlinks.query);
    var result = skimlinks_query({
        searchFor: "title:\"moto g\"",
        fq: "country:US",
        rows:5
    });
    return result;
}
```

to know about asynchronous functions watch [this](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm)

and then in my server side methods call this

```
 apiresult:function()
 {      
    var response = returnAllResult();
    return response.skimlinksProductAPI.products[0].merchant;
 }
```

that's it working fine now. Hope this helps someone

Comment: You had a problem with asynchronity on the server. On Meteor you can use fibers. It's the standard Meteor way.